# Android, services and threading. Why doesn't the thread start running until other execution ends?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                startService(new Intent(BoogerActivity.this, LocalService.class));
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        while(!LocalService.isRunning);
        System.out.println("Why can't you reach here!?");
    }
}
```

-

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    public static boolean isRunning = false;
    IBinder serviceBinder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        System.out.println("Service is running!");
        isRunning = true;
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Shouldn't myThread start executing, set LocalService.isRunning to true and allow the main thread to reach the print statement?  When I try this it always hangs on the while loop, what am I missing?  If I remove the while loop, myThread will execute but only after MyActivity's onCreate method has finished.  Can someone explain to me why they aren't running in parallel?

Comment: try sleeping for a few seconds in the `while(!LocalService.isRunning);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services execute on the UI thread. Since you don't return control to the framework from onCreate, the service doesn't have a chance to start. (Calling `startService` merely requests the framework to start it.) From the [docs on Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html):

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise).

Perhaps if you declared the service to start in its own process, it would start successfully. But then it would be modifying a different `isRunning` variable than the one your activity is seeing.

By the way, a busy wait like your `while` loop is really poor practice in general, and especially on an Android device.

Comment: to add - you can extend IntentService and it will be executed on background thread

Comment: Ah, I had no idea that startService() was merely a request, that makes a lot of sense.  I had read that quote from the docs you posted and was trying to run in a separate thread try to get it to start up right away.  And, yeah this is just a little test code I cooked up so I was a bit lazy, I'd never put a busy wait like that into something outside of my own learning purposes.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

the main thread statement `while(!LocalService.isRunning);` keeps executing consuming the full CPU.. Not advisable method.

What you should do is sleep for sometime in the while loop and then recheck.

```
while(!LocalService.isRunning);
{
    System.out.println("Why can't you reach here!?");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This is better in theory, but isn't going to solve OP's real problem. The real problem is that `onCreate` isn't returning so the service doesn't have a chance to start.